# Magento - is it acceptable to create a collection from within a template

Tags: magento

Just as the title implies, is it acceptable to create and use a collection from within a magento template file?

Comment: As in, best/good practice.  I.e. if another magento developer was to look at my code later, would they hate it.

Comment: Yes, they will hate. Create it at associated block :)

Comment: And also check method `_prepareCollection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say no,  use blocks for this